# Calculate weighted mean of different sized groups with different interests

Tags: mean, weighted-mean

In a conference format you often try to find "the best talk" by letting the attendees vote. Of course the primary factor is the quality of the talk itself. The problem I see is that you have differently sized interest groups per talk skewing the results.

Example: Assume you have one talk with 100 attendees. You get an average of 7.5/10 out of the 100 answers of all attendees. Pretty good talk. Then there is this other talk only relevant for a very small special interest group with 5 attendees running in parallel to the other talk. As they're all friends they all vote with 10/10. Just using a mean would let the small talk win "the best talk".

Is this fair? Using a minimum number of responses as a cut-off point doesn't seem fair. Shouldn't a weighted average be used, using the sample size as weight?

What is the best / most fair way to figure out "the best" talk?

Answer (score 1):

I think your hypothesis that group size affects the average score should be formally tested first. If you have data from previous conferences, you could regress average score of the talk on group size to see if it is a significant predictor.

If it turns out to be significant, you can use its regression parameter to "penalize" the average score of future talks.